# Updating the same MySql table each second using AJAX

Tags: mysql, ajax

I have a lobby page that goes to the MySql database every second and checks each timestamp variable(belongs to the users) from a table and if the timestamp is older than (NOW() - 3) seconds, it sets the 'connection'(bool) variable to false. Basically it checks all currently connected users.

I haven't tested on a real server yet, but I have a feeling that it's going to be really intensive process. Because every user has access to the lobby area and each user will send a request to the MySql database and update the table. That means if I have 1000 users in the lobby area that means 1000 requests per second. 
My question is, is there any other way to do the same thing without sending so many requests? I looked into Cron jobs, but cron doesn't let you to run a specific script every 1 second. I think the minimum is 1 minute.

Comment: what type of table are you using?

Comment: My first thought here was that every second was a bit short and it would be 1000 reads and 1000 updates per second, you should have a very high end database server with good planning for blocking/locking in place.

Comment: I don't understand why its such a difficult task. theoretically if one person left his computer on at the lobby page, every user should get the updated info.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you run your script twice every 1 minute:

```
function for_cron() {
  //database update code
}
function check_up() {
   //assuming you dont have anything to echo
   //call the function
   foo_cron();
   sleep(30);  //sleep 30 seconds
   for_cron();
}
Then setup your "check_up" function to run on cron for every 1 minute
```

Hopt it helps